# How to have C# DLL build during install using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, c#, dll, python.net, pyproject.toml

I have a Python project and a file in there calls on a C# dll located inside of a folder called `my_csharp_code` using `Pythonet`. Is there a way to only include the `.cs` file and have the dll build on install? Or is there a better way to do this?

I am using pyproject.toml but not familiar with how it works.